# What variable should I put into this declaration to make it work?

Tags: java, readfile

So I have this code that pops up a file chooser and reads the file:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(); 
File file = null; 
int returnValue = chooser.showOpenDialog( null ) ; 
if( returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ) { 
   file = chooser.getSelectedFile() ;
} 
if(file != null) { 
   String filePath = file.getPath();
} 

// String filePath (that's what i'm trying to input) = "Users/Bill/Desktop/hello.txt";
try { 
   ReadFile files = new ReadFile(***);
   String[] lines = files.OpenFile();
```

the three asterisks (***) represent the class path of the file to be read. What should I put there if I want to read the file? Before this, I hard-coded the class-path and passed it in and it worked, but now, the class-path can be whatever the user chooses. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Again move  `String filePath` to outer scope so it is accessible beyond the `if-block`.

Comment: or better -- move the try block inside of the if block because you're not going to want to read the file if there is none.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what your `ReadFile` thing is, but it looks like it takes a string representing the file path.  In which case, you probably want to give it `file.getPath()`.

Comment: Now my question is: how can I take the text that's printed out (System.out.println) and put into a new text file?

Comment: @Irvilinus: That sounds like a completely separate question.  So create a new question!  (with code)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead of your code in try block:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(filePath);
FileWriter outputStream = new FileWriter("filename.txt");;
int c;

while ((c = fr.read()) != -1) {
    outputStream.write(c);
}
```